# Why does dllexport compiling not specialized template member function?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, dllexport

I have a base class template which has 2 parameters, T is the derived class, flag means I want to activate some feature, default as false:

```
template 
<
    typename T, 
    bool flag
>
class SomeBase
{
public:
    static Info& GetInfo()
    {
        static Info& instance = CreateInfo<T>(T::ClassName());
        static bool inited = false;
        if (!inited)
        {
            Test<flag>(instance);
            inited = true;
        }
        return instance;
    }

private:
    template<bool enable>
    static void Test(Info& instance)
    {
        return;
    }
    template<>
    static void Test<true>(Info& instance)
    {
        T::Add(fields);
    }
};
```

and to use this base:

```
class /*dllexport*/ MyClass : public SomeBase<MyClass, false>
{
public:
    // ...
};
```

The `flag` template parameter is set to false, so according to my specialization, it should compiles the upper empty function, and the compiler does it, which is fine.

But, if I add `dllexport` to `MyClass`, then the compiler is giving C2039, which says `'Add' is not a member of MyClass`, which doesnt make sense, because I am using `SomeBase` as `flag == false`.

**Why does adding `dllexport` makes compiler try to compile the wrong specialization?**

////////////////////////////////////////
Edit 1:
////////////////////////////////////////
According to this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twa2aw10%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Is the statement `when one or more of the base classes is a specialization of a class template` talking about `SomeBase<MyClass, false>`?

If so, `the compiler implicitly applies dllexport to the specializations of class templates` means the compiler is adding `dllexport` to `SomeBase<MyClass, false>`.

And, since I've already fully specialized `static void Test(Info& instance)`, the compiler should choose the correct version of `Test()`, which is `Test<false>()`.

So how come it is choosing(or compiling) the wrong version (`Test<true>()`)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think having dllexport on a template class doesn't make much sense. You'll need to have the full header file at usage time anyway. The compiler probably tries to create a full definition of the class for the linker, which just won't work.

Comment: Hi, I am `dllexport`ing `MyClass`, not `SomeBase`. `MyClass` is not a class template, right?

Answer (score 0):

Without dllexport, you will get the same error when you invoke MyClass::GetInfo from main.
In this case, compiler is expanding and compiling only part code that is invoked.
But with dllexport, it expands and compiles everything.

You can validate with this

```
template <typename T>
class SomeBase
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        dafsaf;
    }
private:
};

class /*__declspec(dllexport)*/ MyClass : public SomeBase<MyClass>
{
public:
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    MyClass o;
    //o.test();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I have no error without dllexport :/ You said "it expands and compiles everything", is there any reference to this behavior? thanks!

Comment: You can refer to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twa2aw10%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, search and read around "the compiler implicitly applies dllexport to the specializations of class templates"

Comment: Hi, I've read this, but am not quite sure about what it means. Is the statement `when one or more of the base classes is a specialization of a class template` talking about `SomeBase<MyClass, false>`? If so, `the compiler implicitly applies dllexport to the specializations of class templates` means the compiler is adding `dllexport` to `SomeBase<MyClass, false>`, and, since I've already fully specialized `static void Test(Info& instance)`, the compiler should choose the correct version of `Test()`. So how come it is choosing(or compiling) the wrong version?